# Turning a dataframe into named list

Tags: r

I have a data frame of colors and ids and want to turn them into a list with the colors as the `name` and the id as the `value`

```
colors <- data.frame(color = c('Gold', 'Green', 'Red'), id = c('1','2','3'))
```

this is a small sample of the data frame, as there are a lot more rows.

I am trying to get the results to be equivalent as the output when you write:

```
colorlist <- list('Gold' = 1, 'Green' = 2, 'Red' = 3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setNames(as.list(as.character(colors$id)), nm = colors$color)
$Gold
[1] "1"

$Green
[1] "2"

$Red
[1] "3"
```

Comment: Your solution is not robust. Please try `colors <- data.frame(color = c('Gold', 'Green', 'Red', "Gold"), id = c('1','2','3', "4"))`

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

With split:

```
colorlist = split(x=colors$id, f=colors$color)
```

If levels are a problem just turn the id into character:

```
colorlist = split(x=as.character(colors$id), f=colors$color)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
colors <- data.frame(color = c('Red', 'Green', 'Gold'), id = c('1','2','3'))

colors_list <- as.list(as.character(colors$id))
names(colors_list) <- colors$color

colors_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Looks a lot like MKBakker's solution. I added `as.integer()` so the result as you described:

```
colorlist <- as.list(as.integer(colors$id))
names(colorlist) <- colors$color
```